# Get the streaming url for radio

Tags: streaming, url, internet-radio

Please help me get the streaming url for this radio. I've tried URL snooper and Firebug but has not worked.

http://jesusislordradio.snack.ws/ This is the radio link, into the website.

Answer (score 0):

There is no streaming URL per se for this radio. It uses Ustream, which in turn uses a flash player.

This flash player makes requests to the Ustream servers to figure out to which CDN node to talk. Then it just contacts that node and asks it for chunks of audio. The node sends those as FLV encapsulated data. So it's not a continuous stream of data, but intermittent download of chunks.

You'd have to check if anyone reverse-engineered Ustream if you want to play it back otherwise. The URL to the Ustream page of that radio is: http://www.ustream.tv/channel/jesusislord-radio